# A primitive of that function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am looking for a primitive of that function $x^5 \arcsin(x^3)$ Does anyone knows how to do? Thanks !

Comment: $$x^5 = \frac13(3x^2)x^3$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the obvious substitution $t=x^3$.